# Initializing the model on tensorflow consumes 18 gigabytes of video memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am trying to finetune mobilenetV2 with tensorflow.
But when I initialize it with:

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False, 
                                               weights="imagenet")
```

it consumed 18gb VRAM, so i cant train it. How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the input shape?

Comment: I use this all the time with no problem. Please provide input shape you used

Comment: 96x96, tensorflow libraries versions:tensorboard                  2.8.0
tensorboard-data-server      0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit       1.8.1
tensorflow                   2.7.0
tensorflow-estimator         2.7.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.23.1